# get specific string from with neo4j cypher

Tags: node.js, api, rest, neo4j, cypher

i have this function to get hastag from description of node Image
when i put the keyWord manually it's work

```
exports.hashtag = function (req, res) {
    var query = [
            'start n = node(*) where n.description =~ \'(?i).*({hashtagss}).*\' return n ' 
    ].join('\n')


var params = {
    hashtagss: req.params.hashtagss
};

Image.query(query, params, function (err, images) {
    if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
    else return res.status(200).json({hashtags:images});
});
```

};

but when i send a parameter i get this error message

```
    {
"message": "The statement has been closed.",
"name": "Neoprene"
}
```

any solution please

Comment: This is a params name that i choose -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find this solution
it's work for me
that's exactly what i need

```
exports.hashtag = function (req, res) {

    var hashtag = req.params.hashtag;

    var query = [
            'MATCH (imageTag:Image) WHERE imageTag.description =~ \'(?i).*'+hashtag+'.*\'  return imageTag'

    ].join('\n')



    Image.query(query, function (err, images) {
        if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
        else return res.status(200).json({hashtags:images});
    });
};
```

Comment: This query isn't good, it won't be cached. You're better off using Michael Hungers solution below, or at least parameterizing it: MATCH (imageTag:Image) WHERE imageTag.description =~ {hashtagss}

Comment: My goal is to have a word in a whole String
for this I used this cypher

Comment: That's fine but a partial String param won't be resolved. Instead the param hashtagss will now have a value of '(?i).*(' + hashtagss + ').*' so you're still doing a regexp match but with a properly parameterized query.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is not good at all

1. don't use a scan over all nodes, use labels!
2. parameters are not resolved *within* strings
3. when inserting the data pull out hashtags as separate nodes that are connected to your content nodes

#### Your example

```
MATCH (n:Content)
WHERE n.description =~ '(?i).*('+{hashtagss}+').*' 
return n
```

#### Better:

```
MATCH (n:Content)<-[:TAGGED]-(t:Tag)
WHERE t.name IN {hashtags} 
return n, collect(t.name) as tags
```

Comment: My goal is to have a word in a whole String for this I used this cypher